# Handling null values with PowerShell dates

Tags: oracle, powershell

I'm working on a module to pull data from Oracle into a PowerShell data table, so I can automate some analysis and perform various actions based on the results. Everything seems to be working, and I'm casting columns into specific types based on the column type in Oracle. The problem I'm having has to do with null dates. I can't seem to find a good way to capture that a date column in Oracle has a null value.

Is there any way to cast a `[datetime]` as null or empty?

Comment: What do you expect as a result of that cast? I mean casting [datetime] to null or empty string won't result in a date object. So, I am failing to understand the need. Would you instead be OK to replace a null or empty value in that column with a default date?

Comment: I thought about that, but it's not my preference. Much of my analysts uses dates, so that adds complexity.

Comment: Basically all I'm after is a way to quickly identify that the value is empty. With columns containing strings in currently setting them as $null, and I'd like similar functionality for dates.

Comment: $null should work for date column too once you find that the column value is empty.

Comment: When I set it as $null I get an error saying to use DBNull instead. When I try to set it as DBNull I get an error saying it couldn't store system.dbnull in a datetime field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy function to test if a value from a database column is NULL:

```
function test-sqlnull{
Param($value)
  return  [System.DBNull]::Value.Equals($value)
}
```

If you need to store a null in a datetime field, just set it to [DBNull]::Value.

Comment: "I can't seem to find a good way to capture that a date column in Oracle has a null value."  I thought that's what you meant.  I'll add some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution that will work. Rather than attempting to set the field as null or empty, I'm not setting it at all. Now the empty value can be identified by checking if the file type is `[System.DBNull]`.

```
$data | ? {$_.myDate.GetType() -eq [System.DBNull]}
```